# Can threads in Java cache a final field?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I declared the following array:

```
private final int[] array = new int[10];
```

Now, if I start 10 threads each writing a value to its own key (Thread 1 writes to   `array[0]`, Thread 2 writes to `array[1]`, etc) will any thread try to cache array or all changes will be made in the main memory?

Comment: The question is valid, but it *may* be the wrong one to ask. The question is : what do you want to do ? Do you want to read `array[0]`, supposedely written by the `thread 0` from another thread (say `thread 1̀`) ? In Java, thinking in terms of "main memory" and "CPU caching" has little sense, as these do not always exist as such at the Java runtime level (specification wise). What you want to reason about is "happens before relationships", which is roughly "what guarantees that a write will be readable by a thread, and when will it be". This is what is specified, and what you can rely upon.

Comment: If you don't put some mechanism in place, threads are not guaranteed to see changes other threads make. If each thread is only writing and reading from it's own slot, then they'll always see their own up-to-date value.

Comment: On top of my previous comment, "caching" the `array` field is one thing, caching of each and every one of the ten individuals ints of this field is another, which is a reason more to re-frame the question to make sure we can help you with a valid answer.

Comment: @matt **but** if every thread is limited to its own array index, there's no point sharing the array anyway. Each thread should use a field or local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread can cache any non-volatile value.

In particular, code for a thread can inline into code a `boolean` value that thread doesn't change. The thread might not detect a change until it is recompiled.

In this case, both the array reference and the values in the array will be cached, but most likely will see the new value after some time.

The use of `final` makes no real difference. One reason is that reflection allows you to change `final` fields.

A cleaner way to have a thread safe array like this is to use `AtomicIntegerArray` added in Java 5.0

```
final AtomicIntegerArray array = new AtomicIntegerArray(10);

public void increment(int n) {
    array.incrementAndGet(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, final has no visibility semantics for individual array elements, even a volatile would only guarantee a [happens before order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) on the reference mutation itself not the elements. For that you would need to synchronize or use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The `final` modifier makes sure all the `Thread`-s can see the initialized value of *that reference*. This is important: the `final` keyword refers only to the array, but not to the values stored within that array.

### Original answer

We don't **know** what is going to happen. The JVM might or might not cache the values. I suggest not to build any dependency on this.

I think you will want some visibility. In general, you can force visibility with either the `volatile` keyword or with `synchronization`. In this case you have an array if integers.

#### An array of `AtomicInteger`-s

You can replace it with array of `AtomicInteger` -s:

```
private final AtomicInteger[] array = new AtomicInteger[10];
```

But in this case you'll have to manipulate the values somewhat differently:

```
array[0] = new AtomicInteger(0);
array[0].incrementAndGet();
```

#### A concurrent list

Another approach is to use a concurrent list, like `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or use the `Collections.synchronizedList()` wrapper method:

```
// option 1
private final List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

// option 2
private final List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Either way, you'll have somewhat different accessors than those of an `array`. The List initialization is the most tricky part:

```
// this prevents all kinf of OutOfBoundsException-s
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(0);
}
// and now you can use it
list.set(0, list.get(0) + 1);
```

#### A concurrent map

You can also use map, so you can skip the problematic initialization:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// ...
map.putIfAbsent(0, 0);
map.put(0, map.get(0) + 1);
```

Comment: `AtomicIntegerArray` seems like a more natural choice.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I didn't even know about it. I'll browse the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` now.

Comment: Re, "...the array, not...the values stored _in_ the array." Most experienced programmers will immediately understand what you're saying there, but IMO that phrasing is not explicit enough for the newbies who come here for help.  They don't fully understand that the `array` variable is _not_ the array. They don't get that the value of `array` is only a pointer that tells the JVM where to find the array--some where else on the heap.

Comment: I think I found the right wording. Anyway, should the OP ask, I will happily add more examples.